# Retrieve the elements of ArrayList using struts 2 tag without using s:iterate

Tags: java, jsp, tags, struts2

Source Code of LoginAction.java

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LoginAction {

    private List list;

    public void setList(List list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public String execute() {

        list = new ArrayList();

        list.add(new Questions("Pet Name", "Junk"));

        list.add(new Questions("Nick Name", "Bunk"));

        list.add(new Questions("Real Name", "Hunk"));

        return "SUCCESS";
    }

}
```

Source Code of Questions.java

```
package com.test;
public class Questions {

    private String question;
    private String answer;

    public Questions(String question, String answer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
}
```

In JSP:

The given statements

```
 <s:property="list[0]"/>
```

give outputs

com.test.Questions@32bf232e1

How can i fetch the value Question object using struts2 tag without using iterator?

Comment: You _are_ fetching the object. That's its `toString()` output. Call the sub-property you want, as Thomas has shown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `<s:property="list[0].question"/>`.

Or `<s:set name="question" value="list[0]"/>` and then `<s:property="#question.question"/>`.

Comment: It's always nice to get rated down without explanation ;)

Answer (score -2):

Another way to get the value of a `Question` object is to add this tag:

```
<s:property value="list" />
```

And then adding a `toString` method in the `Questions` class.